# error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe when paypal calls back to python django app

Tags: python, django, paypal

Hi I am doing papal integration with my django app.

i am using latest version of django from svn and python 2.6.

However, i found every time when paypal's sandbox accessing my notify url i got 500 [Errno 32] Broken pipe my django stack.

Does anyone have similar experience with this ?

Cheers,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 281, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 321, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 417, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 318, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('216.113.191.33', 21736)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 562, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 618, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 661, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error **Connection reset by peer** show you that the connection have been closed by peer (in your case Pypal) and for the Error **Broken pipe** this error is raised when a connection is closed suddenly without informing the other peer (in your case your machine).

Comment: so is there anything i can do to prevent this happening?
As i am testing against paypal sandbox, not sure this symptom will disappear if i use paypal live settings.
Thanks

Comment: also, i deployed this by using uwsgi+nginx, i still got 500.

Comment: @Grace Ladder : like i said it's paypal that reset the connection , maybe you can edit your answer and add the code that you use to connect to paypal , hope this can help !

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.  First, some of the paypal APIs (particularly MassPay) are terribly poor.

The second, and more likely, problem, is that your server is single-threaded and is having trouble properly raising an exception to paypal.  I was able to resolve a similar problem by creating an html file with a form (via POST) that mocked a paypal IPN and then looking at the debug result (or better, using a debugger like the one in PyDev).  You could do the same thing with curl of course.

Comment: the funny thing was i tried with curl to mimic the post data, django server was survived, but get screwed when paypal called back. will do more checking shortly, cheers