# How to stream videos using Django website?

Tags: html, django, video-streaming

I am developing a website with django . I wanted to embed a video which is iterated through a for loop.

```
{% for i in ImageData %}
<td>
<object width="425px" height="360px" >
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<param name="movie" value="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ i.video }}"/>
<embed src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ i.video }}" width="425" height="360" allowFullScreen="true" type="video/avi" wmode="transparent"/>
<\td>
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting the video on the page, but not able to stream it. !! Can anyone please help me?

working on localhost:8000, it does show me a video box but cannot run .

**Update:**
This is the error i got in the terminal when the django server is run, the website is still on the Chorme (in Ubuntu)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 416, in write
    self._write(data[offset:offset+chunk_size])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 318, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 48640)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 570, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 618, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 661, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

**Further**:
The other thing i noticed, is that this error occurs only in **google-chrome** and not in **firefox4** .. Any step i should follow to get it corrected ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What format are you videos in? Where are they hosted?

Comment: @stevejalim : video format is .avi and hosted on ubuntu django server

Comment: What does "cannot run" mean? we need more detail if you want help

Comment: Perhaps it's because you didn't close the `<object>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of error is not from Django. But the Google Chrome might have some error connecting!

Here are many such errors where they tell its browser fault:

- [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029297/error-errno-32-broken-pipe-when-paypal-calls-back-to-python-django-app)
- [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868059/django-webkit-broken-pipe)
- [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4444)

Answer (score 0):

Django has nothing to do with this, really.

AVI video cannot just run as an `<embed>`. You should use either [HTML5 `<video>` tag](http://www.html5video.org/) (won't work in every browser), or convert your video to `.flv` and use a flash player, like [OSPlayer](http://www.osflv.com/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may be encountering a problem with Django's lack of support for [HTTP `Range` requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) - which are commonly used with video streaming. So you're probably better off using Django in conjunction with a webserver (e.g. Nginx, Apache) so Django handles the dynamic content with the media content is provided directly by the webserver. See this Question for more details:
[Byte Ranges in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324250/byte-ranges-in-django)